# Cut hole in surface of mesh without adding faces

Tags: boolean-modifier

I want to cut holes in the face of a object using other objects. Normally this would be done with the Boolean operator. However the Boolean operator leaves "caps" on the holes that I have to manually delete (left side of picture). How do I do this without creating the extra faces from the "caps" (right side if picture)?

[image]

I am on blender version 4.0

Answer (score 0):

The *Boolean* modifier will have the desired result if each face is considered to be a separate object. The steps are:

[image]

### Apply the Boolean modifier

Select the main object, add a *Boolean* modifier with the *Difference* setting, select the *Object* as the cutting object, select just the cutting object, press <kbd>H</kbd> to hide the cutting object.

### Separate the object into individual faces

Select the main object, press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to enter *Edit Mode*, press <kbd>A</kbd> to select all, press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> and chose *Faces by Edges* to separate the individual faces. Press <kbd>P</kbd> and click *By Loose Parts* to make everything separate objects. Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to exit *Edit Mode*, go to the menu *Object > Convert > Mesh* to convert the modifier to a mesh. Manually delete any faces the *Boolean* operator messed up on.

### Join the faces back into one object

Select all the loose faces, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> to join them, press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to enter *Edit Mode*, press <kbd>A</kbd>to select all, click *Mesh > Cleanup > Merge by Distance* to merge them into one object again.

Comment: Selecting all then splitting faces by edges and separating by loose parts is a bit overkill. In this case with a simple cube it would only produce 6 separate objects, with a slightly more complex geometry this could easily become a mess. Instead, select the face that should have the holes, then without splitting press `P` > _Selection_ and that is all for the second step. That's also less duplicate vertices in the end that need to be merged (although this does not really matter).

Comment: You might also want to check out the [Ctrl-F > Intersect Knife](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/face/intersect_knife.html) tool